# How do I write a batch script that copies one directory to another, replaces old files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like a batch script in Windows with which I can copy one directory to another. If this directory already exists, and then for each file that already exists in both with the same name and location, it should be overwritten, if it does not exists, it should just be added.

In the end it should be a batch script to which I can pass 2 arguments, source & destination.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your batch file do this

```
set source=C:\Users\Habib\test
set destination=C:\Users\Habib\testdest\
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
```

If you want to copy the sub directories **including empty directories** then do:

```
xcopy %source% %destination% /E /y
```

If you only want to copy sub directories and not empty directories then use `/s` like:

```
xcopy %source% %destination% /s /y
```

Comment: I think you need the /E flag too, as Bali mentioned below.

Comment: @Samuel, if the OP has to copy "Empty" directories along with sub directories then "/E" would be useful. But OP doesn't need it.

Comment: Yes this clarifies it. Thanks!

Comment: it is possible set destination=//192.168.1.53\testdest\  which mean paste the folder in another system

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the latest function for this in windows 7 is robocopy.

Usage example:

```
robocopy <source> <destination> /e /xf <file to exclude> <another file>
```

/e copies subdirectories including empty ones, /xf excludes certain files from being copied.

More options here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the "xcopy" command?

The xcopy command will do all that for you.

Comment: A short sample of how to use it in this case, or at least a link to documentation would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`xcopy %1 %2 /y /e`

The `%1` and `%2` are the source and destination arguments you pass to the batch file. i.e. `C:\MyBatchFile.bat C:\CopyMe D:\ToHere`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `xcopy /y source destination`