# A script that will copy files and move them into another folder

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I know it seems like this question has been asked a million times, but I think that my predicament is a little different and I can't find anything that serves my purpose. If this has already been asked and I've just missed it somehow, please refer me to that question.

I have three files that need to be copied from one folder into another, where those files may already exist.

So for example `C:\Program Files\file.dll` needs to be moved to `C:\Program Files (x86)` where the `file.dll` may already exist. I also need the source files to stay in its directory.

I know the `MOVE [source][destination]` will move the files from the source which will delete them.

I've tried this :

```
set source=C:\Program Files\file.dll
set destination=C:\Program Files (x86)\
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
```

that I found here: [How do I write a batch script that copies one directory to another, replaces old files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904608/how-do-i-write-a-batch-script-that-copies-one-directory-to-another-replaces-old)

but I get the message "invalid number of parameters".

Am I missing something silly ? Is there a simple way of doing this? Even a hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the paths have spaces in them you may need:

```
xcopy "%source%" "%destination%" /y
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to copy all file from source folder to destination.

This can also add the new flooder name on your give path or copy it to exist folder.

`powershell Copy-Item -Path "C:Source\floder" -Destination "C:\Destination"  -Recurse`